# Is creating a fake file that's not in use a viable honey pot?

Tags: security, wordpress, honeypot

We currently host upwards of 300 wordpress sites/installations, and I am experimenting with beefing up WordPress security through some homemade efforts.

As an IT guy, I watch logs .. All the time, watching logs, and I noticed an inordinate amount of hits on `xmprpc.php` --  So I thought, if we're not using it, and really given our niche nobody legitimately should be hitting the file, why disable it?  Why not create a honey pot?

What I did, in the installation(s) I symlinked `xmlrpc.php` to a `php` file on the server backend.  IE

```
ln -s /var/www/myScripts/honeyPot/xmlrpc.php /var/www/example_0.com/xmlrpc.php
ln -s /var/www/myScripts/honeyPot/xmlrpc.php /var/www/example_1.com/xmlrpc.php
ln -s /var/www/myScripts/honeyPot/xmlrpc.php /var/www/example_2.com/xmlrpc.php
```

I then made the file immutable to prevent tampering:

```
chmod 0 /var/www/myScripts/honeyPot/xmlrpc.php
chattr +i /var/www/myScripts/honeyPot/xmlrpc.php
```

My version of `xmlrpc` simply collects various information via the `_SERVER` `_POST` `_GET` and `_SESSION`.  It then proceeds to grab the `CIDR` for that specific user's IP address via an API.

So for instance this IP `40.69.167.21` hit and the API came back with `Microsoft Corporation | CIDR 40.64.0.0/13`

My script then proceeds to store gathered info, and the offending `CIDR` in a MySQL table, at which point a CRON script I've written inserts the rule into the UFW firewall.

```
 ufw insert 1 deny from 40.64.0.0/13 to any
```

Because I am blocking entire IP blocks, over the past 2 weeks this has dramatically reduced web traffic and log entries.  I have had no complaints thus far from clients and all seems well so far.  Can anyone see any drawbacks of using a file that shouldn't be used on our setup anyway to trap these IPs as they come in?

Furthermore is this a viable solution for the 15 or so file names that we don't use, but get hit on a regular basis by bots looking to exploit?

This was mainly an experiment, but I think I may be onto something there.

Comment: So you've essentially reimplemented a limited version of [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/)? With the addition that you've given php the (indirect) ability to ban IPs which worsens exploit scenarios.

Comment: Not quite on the `php` end .. PHP just stores the CIDR in a database .. I have written a `bash` script run by a CRON job that enters the UFW rules ..  So there is a handoff there.  So what sort of issue do you see?  A blanket statement *"worsens exploit scenarios"* -- Can you give me an example?

Comment: If php has the ability to write CIDRs that get banned to a database, php has the ability to ban IPs since all it needs to do is write to a database and boom, banned. Granted an attacker who exploits a vulnerability in WP would have to realise that but he could theoretically ban whoever he wants, including 0/0 amounting to a DOS. I'm not saying it's likely given there are for easier ways to wreck WP but I see no value in the way it currently works when fail2ban does this better by being out of band.

Comment: nitpicking: `chmod 0 ` will prevent the file to do much. If it works at all, that means the application reading it is running as root. About security...